# JOptionPane cannot find symbol in module

Tags: module, joptionpane, cannot-find-symbol

So, the assignment for this week was all about modularization, and the code must contain 6 modules, which is why it looks like a complete mess.  Anyway, I'm getting an error that says the module cannot find JOptionPane even though I declared it for the main method.  I've posed the code below.  Any help appreciated.

Specifically, I'm getting it right here, with this line of code posted at the top.

```
{  public static String getItemShape ()


{
  String typeOfShape;

  typeOfShape = JOptionpPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 'C' for a Circle, or 'S' for a Sphere"); //getting input for shape

  return typeOfShape; //returning to method

}
```

}

```
//This program will find the area or volume of a circle or sphere, 
respectively.

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Java_Chapter_9

{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    //Declarations

    String itemShape;   //type of shape
    String runProgram;   //user control
    Double itemRadius;  //radius of tem
    Double finalAnswer;  //calculation for final answer

    //End Declarations

    showGreeting ();  //Call greeting module

    runProgram = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 'Y' to run the 
program, or 'N' to quit");  //giving user control

    while (runProgram.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) //loop for continuous use

    {
      itemShape = getItemShape ();  //calling itemShape module

      itemRadius = getItemRadius ();  //calling itemradius module

      finalAnswer = calculateAnswer (itemRadius, itemShape);  //calling the 
module for calculation with paramaters

      runProgram = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'Y' to input more, or 
'N' to Quit");
    }  

    showGoodbye ();

  }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////// starting modules


    public static void showGreeting ()  //greeting module

    {

      System.out.println("Welcome to the program");
      System.out.println("This program will show you the area or volume of a 
shape");
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating modules
    public static String getItemShape ()


   {
      String typeOfShape;

      typeOfShape = JOptionpPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 'C' for a 
Circle, or 'S' for a Sphere"); //getting input for shape

      return typeOfShape; //returning to method

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating modules
    public static double getItemRadius ()

    {
      double radiusOfItem;  //variable withing scope of module
      String radiusofItemInput;

      radiusOfItemInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the 
radius of the item in inches: ");

      radiusOfItem = Double.parseDouble(radiusofItemInput);
      return radiusOfItem;    
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating modules  
    public static double calculateAnswer (double itemRadius, string itemShape);

     { 
      double circleArea; 

      if (itemShape.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
      {

        circleArea = 3.14159 * (itemRadius * itemRadius);

        system.out.print("The area of the circle in inches is "  + circleArea);

        return circleArea;
      }


        else 
        {

             calculateAnswerSphere (itemRadius, itemShape);
        }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////// seperating method

        {
          double sphereVolume;

          sphereVolume = (4.0/3) * 3.14159 * (itemRadius * itemRadius * 
itemRadius);

          system.out.print("The volume of the sphere in cubic inches is " 
+sphereVolume);
        }

        end If;

    }


    public static void showGoodbye ()    
    {
      System.out.println("Thank you for using the program. Goodbye.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Any update for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway, I'm getting an error that says the module cannot find
>   JOptionPane even though I declared it for the main method

You have a typo in this line

```
 typeOfShape = JOptionpPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 'C' for a Circle, or 'S' for a Sphere"); //getting input for shape
```

It should be `JOptionPane` instead of `JOptionpPane`. Remove the `p`